# How to take all scenarios backup in odi in one go

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

How to export all the scenarios in odi in one go to make a local backup. Each scenario must be imported as single unit.

Comment: Are you saying you want to export all your scenarios and import it in another work repository? What do you mean by single unit? Which version of ODI do you have?

Comment: No, i want to export each scenario in my local disk and want to keep it as backup , i don't want to import it to another work rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **OdiExportAllScen** tool can be used in a package or a procedure to export all the scenarios. If there is no need to save the passwords that might be linked to dataserver, the export key can be left blank but *Export without Cipher Text data* has to be set to *Yes*.
[image: OdiExportAllScen in a package]

Execute the package and make sure you use the local agent for a local export, not an agent on the server.

Comment: Well yes, just create a scenario from that package, export it, import it into QA or PROD repository and execute it there.

Comment: can we take backup of all scenarios in single go from execution repo. e.g QA or PROD .

Comment: As I already answered before you deleted your comment : "Well yes, just create a scenario from that package, export it, import it into QA or PROD repository and execute it there."

Comment: No Dear, my question is i need to export all scenarios from my Execution rep i.e PROD , exportallscen only works on Development enviorment not on execution env.

Comment: Hi, I am trying the below mentioned command on Work Rep. its shows the error "Table and view doesn't exist' OdiExportAllScen "-FROM_PROJECT=2001" "-FROM_FOLDER=16001" "-TODIR=/ftp_aidtm/odi/NGDC_DistributionServer" "-FORCE_OVERWRITE=NO" "-RECURSIVE_EXPORT=YES" "-XML_VERSION=1.0" "-XML_CHARSET=ISO-8859-1" "-JAVA_CHARSET=ISO8859_1" "-EXPORT_PACK=YES" "-EXPORT_POP=YES" "-EXPORT_TRT=YES" "-EXPORT_VAR=YES"

Comment: can you help me to get answered one of any question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369398/call-odi-mappig-through-pl-sql-procedure