# Export all scenarios from execution repository(prod) in ODI12c

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have to take backup of all scenarios from execution repository(prod) in my local machine,
do we have any best way to do this(i think exportallscen tool will not work for execution repository)?
basically am looking to automate the process to export all the scenarios,avoid manual work.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take all scenarios backup in odi in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713570/how-to-take-all-scenarios-backup-in-odi-in-one-go)

Comment: Thanks!...however i could not find any solution in that link

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 options to achieve an automatic export of all scenarios :

1. Using the [OdiExportAllScen](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/reference/opentools.htm#ODIRF142) tool directly from the [command line on the agent](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/reference/using_opentools.htm#ODIRF217).
2. Creating a package or a procedure with an [OdiExportAllScen](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/odi/reference/opentools.htm#ODIRF142) tool, generate a scenario and import that scenario on the execution repository. It can then be executed from there. A variable will be needed for the INSTANCE parameter so it can be used in every environment.
3. Using the ODI SDK in Groovy or Java. The method to use is [exportAllScenarios()](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/impexp/support/ExportServiceImpl.html#exportAllScenarios-oracle.odi.domain.project.IOdiScenarioSourceContainer-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-oracle.odi.impexp.EncodingOptions-boolean-boolean-char:A-boolean-) from class ExportServiceImpl. You will need to pass a Project or Folder name to that method though. So if you need to export all the scenarios from a repository, you first need to loop through all the projects.